# How can I actually check the bucket version in Hive?

Tags: hive, version, bucket

As far as I know, the Bucket version information is inserted into the actual Bucket file as binary.
And I know that when hive actually reads that file, it checks the version through Codec, is this correct?

```
 * Represents format of "bucket" property in Hive 3.0.
 * top 3 bits - version code.
 * next 1 bit - reserved for future
 * next 12 bits - the bucket ID
 * next 4 bits reserved for future
 * remaining 12 bits - the statement ID - 0-based numbering of all statements within a
 * transaction.  Each leg of a multi-insert statement gets a separate statement ID.
 * The reserved bits align it so that it easier to interpret it in Hex.
 * ... omitted
```

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/BucketCodec.java

This is a part of the Hive BucketCodec source code. Is what I know correct? I'm curious how you actually check the bucket information.

Also, if the bucket file is saved in ORC format, the top 3 bits are ORC format information. In this case, how do I check the bucket version information?